# C++ passing base type to pure virtual function

Tags: c++, abstract-class, virtual

i want to understand the behavior of pure virtual functions in derived class when passing to it an argument of same type as (abstract) base class.

to clarify the question, i took the following code from GeeksForGeeks and modified it:

```
namespace example {
enum Type {ENGINEER, MANAGER};
class Employee
{
private:    
    const Type worker;
public:
    Employee(const Type& worker) : worker(worker) {}
    virtual ~Employee {}

    virtual void raiseSalary(const Employee&) = 0;
    {  /* common raise salary code */  }

    virtual void promote(const Employee&) = 0;
    { /* common promote code */ }
};

class Manager: public Employee {
    private:
        int degree;
    public:
        //<constructor>\\

    virtual void raiseSalary(const Employee&)
    {  /* Manager specific raise salary code, may contain
          increment of manager specific incentives*/  }

    virtual void promote(const Employee&)
    { /* Manager specific promote */ }
};
```

}

Now, how can we get access to the field `degree` in derived class `Manager` inorder to update his `degree`? since the passed argument to `raiseSalary(Employee& employee)` could be `Manager` or `Engineer`

Comment: using `static_cast` might suggests using `switch` or `if` statments. i am looking for a way to harness the OOP features. is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Your design is probably flawed.  In this case it may make sense to have degree as part of the Employee?

Comment: You can't modify that attribute if is not an attribute of the base class too...

Comment: but say that different types of workers have different private fields. adding them to Employee is pain.

Comment: Why are you passing in employee to non-static methods?

Comment: Yep, is the only way, you can try not passing an Employee(You can use "this" pointer instead) as a parameter, and in that case each subclass should know how to modify that attr when you call that method. Because is a specific attr of the subclass and the base class shouldn't care about that.

Comment: You have "modified" working code into something that doesn't work. You need to understand how that code is supposed to work first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two ways to handle that problem. Let's start with some really bad solution: using casting. In that case `dynamic_cast`. You can try to down cast a type. If `dynamic_cast` isn't able to do that it is going to return a null pointer or throw an exception (depends on wheather you cast a pointer or a value/reference type). But that approach is going to force you to adapt your casts as more Manager, Engineer types are going to come. You might also need to use `friend` to allow specific classes to access internals of others. `friend` is not going to be inherited in the hierarchy, so you are going to end up with many friends => broken, broken, broken :(

An alternative would be to use the Visitor Pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern
Using the visitor pattern you can also make a base no-op visitor and finer grained Visitors to handle specific stuff. Just a small example (with specific visitors without derivation):

```
namespace example {

  class SalaryRaisingVisitor;
  class EmployeePromotingVisitor;

  class Employee
  {
  public:
      Employee() {}
      //don't forget to implement the copy constructor: read more about rule of 3!!!

      virtual ~Employee {}

      virtual void accept(SalaryRaisingVisitor const&) = 0;
      virtual void accept(EmployeePromotingVisitor const&) = 0;
  };

  class Manager: public Employee {
      private:
          int degree;
      public:
          //<constructorS>

      virtual void accept(SalaryRaisingVisitor const& v)
      {
        v.visit(*this, degree); 
      }

      virtual void accept(EmployeePromotingVisitor const& v)
      {
        v.visit(*this, degree);
      }
  };

  class Engineer: public Employee {
      public:
          //<constructorS>

      virtual void accept(SalaryRaisingVisitor const& v)
      {
        v.visit(*this); 
      }

      virtual void accept(EmployeePromotingVisitor const& v)
      {
        v.visit(*this);
      }
  };

  class SalaryRaisingVisitor
  {
    void visit(Manager& m, int& degree) //might be const if no internal state changes
    {
      //...
    }

    void visit(Engineer& e) //might be const if no internal state changes
    {
      //...
    }
  };

}
```

At the end as you deal with C++, try to avoid virtual functions :) and move everything to static polymorphism :)

Answer (score 1):

You should rather structure your code like this:

```
class Employee
{
    virtual void raiseSalary() = 0;
    virtual void promote() = 0;
};

class Manager: public Employee
{    
    virtual void raiseSalary()
    {  /* Manager specific raise salary code, may contain... */ }

    virtual void promote()
    { /* Manager specific promote */ }
};

int main()
{
    Manager bob;
    bob.promote();    // <--- Proper method in the Manager class will be called.
                      // Current instance will always have the right class.
}
```

In other words you should seek opportunity to pass the specific derived class as the `this` parameter. Unfortunately this will not work in complex cases when multiple params are needed. But well, this was the idea of the language designers. The perfect language is not developed yet.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the concept of virtual functions with classes wrong. The class "knows" what it is (via vtable), so you can just write it as class function, not as static global function. Each function inside the class knows all class variables, so you don't have to pass an object of the class.

```
namespace example {
enum Type {ENGINEER, MANAGER};
class Employee
{
private:    
    const Type worker;
public:
    Employee(const Type& worker) : worker(worker) {}
    virtual ~Employee {}

    virtual void raiseSalary() = 0;
    {  /* common raise salary code */  }

    virtual void promote() = 0;
    { /* common promote code */ }
};

class Manager: public Employee {
    private:
        int degree;
    public:
        //<constructor>\\

    virtual void raiseSalary()
    {
    //the Employed standard code
    Employee::raiseSalary(); //This won't compile since you set the virtual function = 0

    //Manager specific raise salary code
    degree = 0; //this lazy bastards should do real work like coding stuff


    }

    virtual void promote()
    { 

    Employee::promote(); //employee common code. This won't compile since you set the virtual function = 0
    /* Manager specific promote */ 
    degree = degree * 2;
    }
};

Employee array[10];
array[0] = Manager(); //create a manager object on the stack
array[1] = Manager(); //create a manager object on the stack
array[0].raiseSalary();  //Only Mananer0 gets raiseSalary
/*the manager object in array[0] uses its virtual function 
to the manager raiseSalary function. The Manager RaiseSalary function
in this case calls the base class raiseSalary function explicitly 
via Employee::raiseSalary();   */
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't and it's the wanted behaviour.

The only way to do this is to cast you argument (which is quite complicated in C++ since you have four different kind of casting). Other solution is to give to any employee a grade attribute.

Alexis.

Comment: You are right, you could static_cast the objects, but I don't think that is what he wants. He probably just wants functions which modify the "this" object.